# Dependency conflict when updating Yum in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos7, yum

On a newly installed CentOS 7 operatind system i am having this error while trying to run yum update

```
 Processing Conflict: kernel-3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 conflicts kmod < 20-9
  --> Finished Dependency Resolution
 Error: Package: firefox-45.6.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: nspr >= 4.11.0
       Installed: nspr-4.10.8-2.el7_1.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           nspr = 4.10.8-2.el7_1
 Error: Package: nss-3.21.3-2.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: nss-softokn(x86-64) >= 3.16.2.3-14.2
       Installed: nss-softokn-3.16.2.3-13.el7_1.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           nss-softokn(x86-64) = 3.16.2.3-13.el7_1
  Error: Package: 1:libguestfs-1.32.7-3.el7.centos.2.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: supermin5 >= 5.1.16-2
       Installed: supermin5-5.1.10-1.2.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           supermin5 = 5.1.10-1.2.el7
  Error: Package: libsemanage-2.5-5.1.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: libsepol.so.1(LIBSEPOL_1.0)(64bit)
  Error: Package: libsemanage-2.5-5.1.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: libsepol.so.1(LIBSEPOL_1.1)(64bit)
  Error: Package: 1:NetworkManager-1.4.0-14.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: glib2 >= 2.46.2
       Installed: glib2-2.42.2-5.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           glib2 = 2.42.2-5.el7
  Error: Package: policycoreutils-2.5-11.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: libsepol.so.1(LIBSEPOL_1.0)(64bit)
  Error: kernel conflicts with kmod-20-5.el7.x86_64
  Error: Package: spice-glib-0.31-6.el7_3.2.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: spice-protocol >= 0.12.11-1
       Available: spice-protocol-0.12.6-2.el7.noarch (base)
           spice-protocol = 0.12.6-2.el7
  Error: Package: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.121-2.6.8.0.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: copy-jdk-configs >= 1.1-3
  Error: Package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.111-2.b15.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: copy-jdk-configs >= 1.1-3
  Error: Package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-11.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: libsepol.so.1(LIBSEPOL_1.0)(64bit)
  Error: Package: 7:lvm2-2.02.166-1.el7_3.2.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: device-mapper-persistent-data >= 0.6.3-1
       Installed: device-mapper-persistent-data-0.5.5-1.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           device-mapper-persistent-data = 0.5.5-1.el7
  Error: Package: kernel-3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: linux-firmware >= 20160830-49
       Installed: linux-firmware-20150904-43.git6ebf5d5.el7.noarch (@anaconda)
           linux-firmware = 20150904-43.git6ebf5d5.el7
  Error: Package: nss-util-3.21.3-1.1.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: nspr >= 4.11.0-1
       Installed: nspr-4.10.8-2.el7_1.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           nspr = 4.10.8-2.el7_1
  Error: Package: policycoreutils-python-2.5-11.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: setools-libs >= 3.3.8-1
       Installed: setools-libs-3.3.7-46.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           setools-libs = 3.3.7-46.el7
  Error: Package: policycoreutils-2.5-11.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: libsepol.so.1(LIBSEPOL_1.1)(64bit)
  Error: Package: policycoreutils-2.5-11.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: libselinux-utils >= 2.5-6
       Installed: libselinux-utils-2.2.2-6.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           libselinux-utils = 2.2.2-6.el7
  Error: Package: spice-glib-0.31-6.el7_3.2.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: usbredir >= 0.6-8
       Installed: usbredir-0.6-7.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           usbredir = 0.6-7.el7
  Error: Package: policycoreutils-2.5-11.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: libsepol >= 2.5-6
       Installed: libsepol-2.1.9-3.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           libsepol = 2.1.9-3.el7
  Error: Package: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.121-2.6.8.0.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: chkconfig >= 1.7
       Installed: chkconfig-1.3.61-5.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           chkconfig = 1.3.61-5.el7
  Error: Package: samba-libs-4.4.4-12.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: libpytalloc-util.so.2(PYTALLOC_UTIL_2.1.6)(64bit)
  Error: Package: 10:qemu-kvm-1.5.3-126.el7_3.3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: libusbx >= 1.0.19
       Installed: libusbx-1.0.15-4.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           libusbx = 1.0.15-4.el7
  Error: Package: nss-3.21.3-2.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: nspr >= 4.11.0
       Installed: nspr-4.10.8-2.el7_1.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           nspr = 4.10.8-2.el7_1
  Error: Package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.111-2.b15.el7_3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: chkconfig >= 1.7
       Installed: chkconfig-1.3.61-5.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           chkconfig = 1.3.61-5.el7
```

For the world i can not figure out how to replace the reference from anaconda to updates and how to resolve the following conflicts.

Most importantly i can not understand why did it happen, because during the previous intallations using exactly the same image i never had the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried clearing yum's metadata cache first?  "yum clean metadata"  or cleaning all cached objects in yum? "yum clean all"

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and I think it was because a yum update got interrupted.

Doing a 'yum clean all' and rebuilding rpm database didn't help.

The first conflict was because I had multiple versions of kmod installed.

If you do a "rpm -qa kmod" and see multiple versions, try uninstalling the older version with "rpm -e kmod-version", then run update again. You might have to uninstall some other conflicting packages as well then reinstall. That eventually fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your yum repositories are out of sync with each other.

Your `base` repository is showing files from CentOS 7.1 or 7.2 (I can't be sure which) but your `updates` repository is showing files from CentOS 7.3.

It *might* be that you simply have out-of-date metadata on your system, in which case you can fix that by running `yum clean all` and then trying to update again.

But it is much more likely that someone has messed with the `base` repo, so as to attempt to force it to remain on 7.1 or 7.2. This is *not* supported, and you should edit the repo file `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` to restore it to its original form.